# What is the best solution for suppressing warning from a MS include (C4201 in mmsystem.h)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings

I am tired of having to look at warnings during our compilations - warnings that come from MS include files.

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\mmsystem.h(1840): warning C4201: nonstandard extension used : nameless struct/union"

I have seen [this thread](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=368375) that suggests changing the header itself (but then each of my team mates has to do it and we have to do it on the build server - not to mention it is a glorious HACK)

Is there a better way?  I don't want to turn it off globally - just to suppress it for certain files or directories.

Any suggestions?

EDIT
For some stupid reason I didn't think I could set warning levels across include files.  Thanks - that does the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like

```
#pragma warning(push, disable: 4201)
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Comment: (+1) wasn't aware you could do the push, disable in the one line :)

Comment: When dealing with 3rd party software, WRAP.

Comment: In VS2012 doing `#pragma warning(push, disable: 4201)` results in `warning C4083: expected 'constant'; found identifier 'disable'`, so I'd recommend sticking with a single instruction per `#pragma warning`.

Answer (score 5):

How about using #pragma warning extension in VC++?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(VS.80).aspx

```
#pragma warning (push, 2)  // Temporarily setting warning level 2
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma warning (pop)      // Restore back
```

You may also try ..

```
#pragma warning (disable: 4201)
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma warning (default)
```

Comment: I don't want to reduce the warning level - I just want to suppress a particular one, but I managed to figure it out.

Comment: But, only for system headers. It's okay to reduce warning level for such system header, that you don't want to modify the source code.

Answer (score 2):

With VS 2017 Community, to avoid warning C4083, I use :

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:4201)
#include <dxvahd.h>
#pragma warning(pop)
```